# Typescript Prototype issue

Tags: typescript

I am having an issue creating a prototype in TypeScript, when I use the method I get "TypeError: t.stringTesting is not a function"

below is the code.

extensions.ts

```
interface String {
    stringTesting() : string;
}

String.prototype.stringTesting = function (): string {
    return "testing"
}
```

in my Angular2 component I am using

```
var t: string = "";
t = t.stringTesting();
alert(t);
```

Comment: Your code is working fine. You probably don't load this `extensions.js` at runtime

Answer (score 1):

> t.stringTesting is not a function"

You need to make sure the `extensions.js` runs *before* any code that uses it.